# How to make four Cesium Label be considered just one object

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have created a billboard with 4 labels, because I need a label with 4 lines, just like this:

[image]

Now I need to drag it aroud by changing the label pixelOffset. Is there a way to make all 4 labels be considered as one and get dragged together?

This is what I have so far, but each line moves individually:

```
pointCollection = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.BillboardCollection());
labelCollection = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.LabelCollection());

pointCollection.add({
    position: pos,
    id: id+ 'point',
    image: pinBuilder.fromColor(Cesium.Color.SALMON, 48)
});

labelCollection.add({
    position: pos,
    id: id + 'label1',
    text: 'Linha1',
    font: '15px Helvetica',
    fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
    outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
    style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-20, 37)
});
labelCollection.add({
    position: pos,
    id: id + 'label2',
    text: 'linha2',
    font: '15px Helvetica',
    fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
    outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
    style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-20, 50)
});
labelCollection.add({
    position: pos,
    id: id + 'label3',
    text: 'linha3',
    font: '15px Helvetica',
    fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
    outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
    style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-20, 65)
});
labelCollection.add({
    position: pos,
    id: id + 'label4',
    text: 'linha4',
    font: '15px Helvetica',
    fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
    outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
    style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-20, 80)
});

var dragging = false;

handler.setInputAction(
    (click) => {
        pickedObject = scene.pick(click.position);
        console.log('teste', pickedObject);
        if (pickedObject && pickedObject.primitive instanceof Cesium.Label) {
            dragging = true;
            initialPositionX = click.position.x - diffX;
            initialPositionY = click.position.y - diffY;
            scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableRotate = false;
            scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableTranslate = false;
        }
    },
    Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_DOWN
);

handler.setInputAction(
    (click) => {
        if (!dragging) return;
        console.log(pickedObject.primitive.pixelOffset);
        diffX = click.endPosition.x - initialPositionX;
        diffY = click.endPosition.y - initialPositionY;
        pickedObject.primitive.pixelOffset = <any>(new Cesium.Cartesian2(diffX, diffY));
    },
    Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE
);

handler.setInputAction(
    (click) => {
        dragging = false;
        scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableRotate = true;
        scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableTranslate = true;
    },
    Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_UP
);
```

I would also like some suggestion about how could I set the offset correctly, because when I drag one label, then click to drag another one the offset starts wrong.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get several labels to move at once, you need to keep track of the labels in groups.  This way, when the user clicks any one of the labels in a group, all of the fellow group members can be quickly found and moved.

In the following example, a new function called `addPin` is used to create a pin with a group of labels, such that the labels can all move toegether.

Here's a [live demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationHelpButton: false,
    animation: false,
    timeline: false
});
var scene = viewer.scene;
var pointCollection = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.BillboardCollection());
var labelCollection = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.LabelCollection());
var pinBuilder = new Cesium.PinBuilder();
var labelGroups = {};

function addPin(id, pos) {
    pointCollection.add({
        position: pos,
        id: id + '|point',
        image: pinBuilder.fromColor(Cesium.Color.SALMON, 48)
    });

    labelGroups[id] = [];

    labelGroups[id].push(labelCollection.add({
        position: pos,
        id: id + '|label1',
        text: 'Linha1',
        font: '15px Helvetica',
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-20, 37)
    }));
    labelGroups[id].push(labelCollection.add({
        position: pos,
        id: id + '|label2',
        text: 'linha2',
        font: '15px Helvetica',
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-20, 50)
    }));
    labelGroups[id].push(labelCollection.add({
        position: pos,
        id: id + '|label3',
        text: 'linha3',
        font: '15px Helvetica',
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-20, 65)
    }));
    labelGroups[id].push(labelCollection.add({
        position: pos,
        id: id + '|label4',
        text: 'linha4',
        font: '15px Helvetica',
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-20, 80)
    }));
}

// NOTE: The pins are added here, by calling the function above.
addPin('a', Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-70, 40));
addPin('b', Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-140, 40));

var dragging = false;
var pickedObjectId;
var lastPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian2();
var diff = new Cesium.Cartesian2();
var scratch = new Cesium.Cartesian2();

var handler = viewer.screenSpaceEventHandler;
handler.setInputAction(
    function (click) {
        var pickedObject = scene.pick(click.position);
        if (pickedObject && pickedObject.id && pickedObject.primitive instanceof Cesium.Label) {
            dragging = true;
            pickedObjectId = pickedObject.id.split('|')[0];
            Cesium.Cartesian2.clone(click.position, lastPosition);
            scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableRotate = false;
            scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableTranslate = false;
        }
    },
    Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_DOWN
);

handler.setInputAction(
    function (click) {
        if (dragging) {
            Cesium.Cartesian2.subtract(click.endPosition, lastPosition, diff);
            Cesium.Cartesian2.clone(click.endPosition, lastPosition);
            var labelsToMove = labelGroups[pickedObjectId];
            var len = labelsToMove.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                var primitive = labelsToMove[i];
                primitive.pixelOffset = Cesium.Cartesian2.add(
                    primitive.pixelOffset, diff, scratch);
            }
        }
    },
    Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE
);

handler.setInputAction(
    function (click) {
        dragging = false;
        scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableRotate = true;
        scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableTranslate = true;
    },
    Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_UP
);
```

Comment: It bothers me when answers consist of code and no explanation at all. Would you consider adding additional details explaining why the approach in the question is wrong, and how your code addresses it?

Comment: My apologies, I was a fairly new user of Stack Overflow in 2015 when this was answered.  Updated.